# Let $X=(0,1)\cup(2,4)$ and $Y=(0,4)$. Why is $(X,\mathcal{U}_{x}$) is not homeomorphic to $(Y,\mathcal{U}_{y})$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=(0,1)\cup(2,4)$ and $Y=(0,4)$. Why is $(X,\mathcal{U}_{x}$) is not homeomorphic to $(Y,\mathcal{U}_{y})$

I was trying to find an open set in X that is not open in Y but I cannot think of one. I was thinking of defining a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and showing is was either not a bijection or an open function but I'm not sure I can do that.

Comment: Is it $X$ connected set? And $Y$?

Comment: And please consider: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The set $(0,1)$ is clopen (both open and closed) in $X$; the only clopen subsets of $Y$ are $Y$ and $\varnothing$.